# jQuery selection of table data inside a form note working

Tags: jquery, forms, html-table, jquery-selectors

I need to create a form that has a table inside. I created the first row of the table ( later more rows will be added), that tags a word based on their grammar.

1. the First column is static ( token)
2. second column tag is fixed/given in html
3. Based on the response from step 2, a variation of options will be in the next column ( state select element).
4. Same thing for the next columns in the table: person and tense.

In the code: I am trying to choose the selector just below the "State" column which is in the table

```
 <td>
 <select id="state" name="state"></select>
</td>
```

and once I get to it, add a few s to that. Please see the code [code](https://www.codeply.com/p/nKQUONmb1s). All my indecies ( ids) are unique. But it seems I cannot select it. To pinpoint it, I tried in the second line of the JavaScript code:

```
 $( "#myForm table tr:nth-child(2)  td:nth-child(3) select" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
```

and also

```
$( "state" ).css( "border", "3px solid red" );
```

But it is not putting any border around the element. "tbody" and nothing works.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: Hi ,where is `source` element and `status` ? Please elaborate more on your issue

Comment: I fixed it and elaborated more on the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Working fine check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qfyb2guo/)